# Why Entity Framework caching query results when i change parameters, I dont deserve it

Tags: caching, entity-framework-6

I have a method, that return a product discounts.

```
public List<OrderDiscount> GetItemDiscounts(string productId, string itemGroup, string resaleTypeIdNewPolicy, string resaleBusinessBranch)
{
    var exeptiondiscount = (from d in Context.Discounts
                            where d.OrderType == "SO"
                               && d.BusinessUnit == "SSP"
                               && d.Currency == "BRL"
                               && d.BusinessBranch == resaleBusinessBranch
                               && ((d.Description == "HGRITEM" && d.ProductId == productId && d.ResaleGroup == resaleTypeIdNewPolicy)
                                   || (d.UnitMeasure == "PC" && (d.Description == "HGRITEM" && d.ItemGroup == itemGroup && d.ResaleGroup == resaleTypeIdNewPolicy))
                                   || (d.UnitMeasure == "PC" && d.Description == "HGRCLI" && d.ResaleGroup == resaleTypeIdNewPolicy && d.ProductId == productId)
                                   || (d.UnitMeasure == "PC" && (d.Description == "HGRCLI" && d.ItemGroup == itemGroup && d.ResaleGroup == resaleTypeIdNewPolicy) || (d.Description == "HGRCLI" && d.ItemGroup == "" && d.ResaleGroup == resaleTypeIdNewPolicy && d.ProductId == "")) 
                           )
                           select d).ToList();

    return exeptiondiscount;
}
```

When it run first time inside a loop, it returns the correct result lines.

In the second time, the parameters productId and itemGroup was changed, but the result not change.

If I run the two queries in DB, results are different.

I do not know why the Entity Framework is caching these results.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Just add ".AsNoTracking()" before the .ToList().

This will cause Entity not to cache the query.